# Is there any way I can auto fill out a textbox from another textbox on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, autofill

I need to copy a value from one text box to another text box. I need to do this for thousands of items on my website. Was wondering if there was any way to do this automatically to save me from copying each individual one across which would take days. Appreciate any help given.

See this image for a magnificent illustration:

[image: 1]

Comment: You can attach an `event listener (onblur)` to your input box and when focus is lost from that textbox it will take its value and set the values of all the other boxes you want filled with that value, of course this will require `javascript`.

Comment: Where's your code, so we can help you? And what have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Also, if this is your website, why send the same value twice, why not just reuse that value in your backend rather than having to input it twice?

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify - Im using a website (ad-lister) to change prices on my website and ebay, amazon etc. I need to fill in the form on ad-lister not on my own website.

Comment: Then you will need to look for some sort of browser extension (or write your own)  - if it's not your site then there is not much you can do.  Unfortunately asking for plugins is specifically off topic on this site

Comment: You need to identify how to differentiate between the 2 text boxes, then you can simply search for the ones you want to get the date from and copy in to the other boxes(given some condition to set it on the proper place) - you basically need something like getElementBy(something) and forEach loop to set values. But without an example by you can't ay much else.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the table id you can use browser conosle to run a Javascript like this,

```
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   row.cells[1].children[0].value = row.cells[0].children[0].value;
}
```

The above will change the cell 2's input with cell 1's input in the whole table. You might need to change the cell number according to the actual table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Table:

<table class="dg" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_cp1_dg" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody><tr>

Input cell:

<td><input name="ctl00$cp1$dg$ctl02$sp" type="text" value="0.00" id="ctl00_cp1_dg_ctl02_sp" autocomplete="off" style="width:60px;text-align:right"></td>

Output cell:

<input name="ctl00$cp1$dg$ctl02$ap" type="text" id="ctl00_cp1_dg_ctl02_ap" autocomplete="off" style="width:60px;text-align:right">

Comment: So the table id is ctl00_cp1_dg_ctl02_sp and the cells ctl00$cp1$dg$ctl02$ap and ctl00_cp1_dg_ctl02_ap